# Play Framework fails to read db config and to inject JPAApi

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying and failing to use play 2.5.

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private JPAApi db;

    @Inject
    public HomeController(JPAApi api) {
        this.db = api;
    }

    public Result index(String name) {
        return ok(views.html.index.render("hello", name, Collections.singletonList("world")));
    }
}
```

My conf\META-INF\persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="readwritePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>ReadWriteDS</non-jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="1" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My conf\application.conf

```
jpa.default=readwritePU

db {
  #pool = "hikaricp"

  default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydbname"
  default.username = "postgres"
  default.password = "123456"
  #default = "default"

  default.jndiName=ReadWriteDS
}
```

The error without and with pool config key enabled in application.conf above:

```
    No configuration setting found for key 'pool'
Error in custom provider, com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'pool'
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for field at play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.scala:80)
  while locating play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$namedDatabaseBindings$1.apply(DBModule.scala:34):
Binding(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider@7af4d3bc)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'pool'

    pool has type STRING rather than OBJECT
Error in custom provider, com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf @ file:/E:/workspace2/coup/target/scala-2.11/classes/application.conf: 344: pool has type STRING rather than OBJECT
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 0 at play.db.DefaultDBApi.<init>(DefaultDBApi.java:27)
  at play.db.DefaultDBApi.class(DefaultDBApi.java:27)
  while locating play.db.DefaultDBApi
  while locating play.db.DBApi
    for field at play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.java:61)
  while locating play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:40):
Binding(interface play.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider@3ec40700)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf @ file:/E:/workspace2/coup/target/scala-2.11/classes/application.conf: 344: pool has type STRING rather than OBJECT
```

I've tried so many different options and combinations, I'm out of ideas. Google doesn't even know the errors. Play just stops working and I have to restart it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jpa.default=readwritePU

db {
    default {
        hikaricp {
            dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
            dataSource {
                serverName = localhost
                databaseName = "mydbname"
                user = "postgres"
                password = "123456"
            }
        }
        jndiName=ReadWriteDS
    }
}
```